# Can i get notion page content using notion api?

Tags: notion-api, notion

I'm planning to make some blog using notion api.

I would like to use the notion api to bring the notion page markdown and show on my blog.

But, I can't find to get page content..

Is there a way to import page markdown content using api?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use Notion's Blocks API. Treat a page as a block, and get its children:

```
curl 'https://api.notion.com/v1/blocks/<your-page-id>/children?page_size=100' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer '"$NOTION_API_KEY"'' \
  -H "Notion-Version: 2022-02-22"
```

Please remember that the content will come up as an array of text pieces that you will need to stitch together.

Comment: hey can you tell how to stitch together then?

Comment: The array elements go in the same order as you typed, so I think you can just concatenate the strings.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot get the page *as markdown* via the API as of the current version, `2022-06-28`. There is an export option in the UI but this is not accessible via the API.

You can get the page content using the [blocks](https://developers.notion.com/reference/retrieve-a-block) endpoint which will return a JSON format of blocks and may require multiple requests to get everything, and the formatting of the text blocks uses a JSON representation for markup as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [notion-to-md](https://github.com/souvikinator/notion-to-md).

Here's an example of an action in Nest. In this case authorization header is `Internal Integration Token` from Notion (you can get it [here](https://www.notion.so/my-integrations/), just create an internal integration) and pageId from body params is just ID of Notion page.

Please note a page you want to get content from, needs to be connected with this integration (see this [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1AHs1.png)).

```
  @Post('/markdown')
  async convertBlocksToMarkdown(
    @Req() request,
    @Body() body,
  ): Promise<{ markdown: string }> {
    const auth = request.headers.authorization;
    const notionClient = new Client({ auth });
    const n2m = new NotionToMarkdown({ notionClient });
    const mdblocks = await n2m.pageToMarkdown(body.pageId);
    const markdown = n2m.toMarkdownString(mdblocks);
    return {
      markdown
    };
  }
```